# Results in for loop repeated too many times - remove duplicates JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to divide the numbers of this array `arr([7,3,14,17])` into even and odd numbers. I have done the following:

```js
var arr = [7, 3, 14, 17]
var o = {
    even: [],
    odd: []
}

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr.map(e => {
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            o.even.push(arr[i])
        } else {
            o.odd.push(arr[i])
        }
    });
}
console.log(o.even);
console.log(o.odd);
```

but the result for the even array is `[ 7, 7, 7, 7, 14, 14, 14, 14 ]` and for the odd array is `[ 3, 3, 3, 3, 17, 17, 17, 17 ]`. Why is this happening? How can I end up with only `[7, 14]` and `[3, 17]` ? Any suggestion/best practice is appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because inside your `for` loop you have a call to `map`, which is itself a replacement of a `for` loop. The fact that you are not using `e` from the closure should serve as a hint that you are doing something incorrectly. You array has 4 elements, so the `for` loop calls `map` 4 times, resulting in 4 duplicates for each value.

Remove `map` to fix the problem:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (i%2 === 0) {
        o.even.push(arr[i])
    } else {
        o.odd.push(arr[i])
    }
}
```

You can also remove `for`, and keep the `map`, but you would need a different overload:

```
arr.map((e, i) => {
    if (i%2 === 0) {
        o.even.push(arr[i])
    } else {
        o.odd.push(arr[i])
    })
```

Comment: Actually having to choose between map and the for, he should remove the for.

Comment: it makes definitely sense. I removed the for and used the map only, but the result is now `undefined` for the even array and `[ undefined, 17, undefined ]` for the odd array...

Comment: @MicheleBoi You need a different overload of `map`, please see the edit.

Comment: the explanation makes totally sense, thanks so much. I ended up using the `for`, as you wrote in the first solution, it's super clean and quick. thanks so much!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight sorry mate, any idea why with both the `map` and the `for` loop the even array results in being `[14, 7]` ? Why is 7 considered even?

Comment: @MicheleBoi Because it's at an even index, the way your solution specifies. If you wanted even values, rather than even indexes, you'd need to use `if (arr[i]%2 ===0)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use built-in prototypes. In this case, [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
o.even = arr.filter((e,i)=>i%2==0);
o.odd = arr.filter((e,i)=>i%2!=0);
```

By the way Array.map already performs a loop, so in your code you perform a loop of loops.
Note that I recommend you use [Array.forEach(](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)) anyway if you want to do that. using the i variable is not really as "Javascript styled" and a less efficient.

Comment: this is another very clean way, I can get away with that without even using `for` or `map`. It's nice to know there's several ways for going from A to B :)

Comment: Yes, I actually recommend this. Generally, built in functions are much better than for s. They also result in less code (often)